# Looking for a server-side js framework which can provide restful service, and works well with angularjs

Tags: javascript, rest, web-frameworks, angularjs

[Angularjs](http://angularjs.org) is a browser-side mvc framework, and communicate server-side via restful-apis.

Normally, any server-side framework which support restful service can work with it, but I'm looking for one can work well with it.

In angularjs, we can use a `$resource` to define a external resource, which has some operations. The code is like:

```
var User = $resource('/users/:id', {}, {
              get: { method: 'GET'},
              create: { method: 'POST'},
              delete: { method: 'DELETE'},
              resetPassword: { method: 'PUT', params: { reset: passord } }
           });
var user = User.get({id: '123'});
user.delete();
```

You can see, the structure of the code is one uri with many operations.

I'm new to server-side js, and just looked a little about [express](http://expressjs.com/). I feel it's not fit angularjs very well.

You can see the demo:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
    res.send('User: ' + id);
});

app.post('/user', function(req, res){
  res.send(req.body);
});
```

It separate one uri by `http-method`s.

I'm looking for a framework, that can let me write the code like:

```
app.route('/user/:id', {
   get: get(req,res) { ... },
   post: post(req, res) { ... },
   resetPassword: put(req, res) {...}
});
```

The code is probably wrong, but I think you may know what I mean: It has similar structure as the angularjs' side.

Is there such frameworks I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use the MongoDB as database take a look in this:

https://github.com/dalcib/angular-phonecat-mongodb-rest

Answer (score 2):

For .NET solution you can check out [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the author's client side router **[Page.js](http://visionmedia.github.com/page.js/)**

If you know how to route an express app, this will be the easiest solution for you. It's also very lightweight